# Proving the raising and lowering of the raising and lowering operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, notation

I am given a written proof of $\hat A^{\dagger}[u_n] = \sqrt{n+1} \ u_{n+1}$, and from it, and told to similarly prove $\hat A[u_n] = \sqrt{n} \ u_{n-1}$.

However, in the written proof for $\hat A^{\dagger}[u_n] = \sqrt{n+1} \ u_{n+1}$, it is formally started with:

$$\hat A^{\dagger}[u_n]=C \ u_{n+1}.$$

Which is an empirically noted equation from the lecture notes. The lecturer then goes on to determine $C$.

$$1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u_{n+1}^* \ u_{n+1} \ dx = 1/C^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\hat A^{\dagger}[u_n])^* \ \hat A^{\dagger}[u_n] \ dx.$$

Which is fine, but then proceeds with:

$$= 1/C^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u_{n}^* \ \hat A \hat A^{\dagger} u_n \ dx.$$

And I don't see how this comes from the previous line, that is to say I don't know how this step makes sense:

$$\text{implication is} \ \ 1/C^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\hat A^{\dagger}[u_n])^* \ \hat A^{\dagger}[u_n] \ dx = 1/C^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u_{n}^* \ \hat A \hat A^{\dagger} u_n \ dx.$$

To me, it should be:

$$1/C^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat A[u_n^*] \ \hat A^{\dagger}[u_n] \ dx$$ or

$$1/C^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat A[u_n] \ \hat A^{\dagger}[u_n] \ dx.$$

Can someone explain why this was done?

Answer (score 1):

They are just using a property of adjoints of matrix products:
$$\left(AB\right)^\dagger=B^\dagger A^\dagger\neq A^\dagger B^\dagger$$

Really it would be better for them to express it as
$$\left(\hat A^{\dagger}[u_n]\right)^\dagger$$
instead of 
$$\left(\hat A^{\dagger}[u_n]\right)^*$$
but either way this is how you get the term
$$u_n^*A$$
on the left side of your integrand. This is why it is not what you propose where $\left(\hat A^{\dagger}u_n\right)^*=Au_n^*$ which is what you propose

---

It seems like the notation being used is kind of sloppy. Really they should do the "matrix manipulations" before they put in the integrals:
$$\langle u_{n+1}|u_{n+1}\rangle=\langle A^\dagger u_n|A^\dagger u_n\rangle=\left(|A^\dagger u_n\rangle\right)^\dagger|A^\dagger u_n\rangle=\langle u_n|AA^\dagger|u_n\rangle$$

Then you can get to the integral you are questioning by expressing the inner products in the position basis.

---

Also, based on the title of your question, it seems to me that you think the adjoint operation $\dagger$ corresponds to a "raising" or "lowering" itself. This is not the case.

Comment: Can you show in your answer explicitly where this identity is being used? I'm still not understanding it.

Comment: @sangstar It is used where you say you don't know how they get to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

$\let\dag=\dagger \def\eqdf{\buildrel \rm def \over =} 
 \def\intinf{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}}$
Unfortunately OP didn't explain his notation and the general context.
As he writes integrals, I guess he's working in Schrödinger
representation and his $u_n$ are eigenfunctions of hamiltonian. More
precisely, I believe he's working with a harmonic oscillator. Also a
notation like $A^\dag[u_n]$ is rather unusual. I'd write simply
$A^\dag u_n$.

Scalar product of two wavefunctions $f$, $g$ is defined by
$$\intinf f^* g\>dx.$$

In this context, the adjoint of an operator is defined as follows. Given an operator $A$, its action on a wavefunction $f$ is known and is
written $Af$. If I want to define $A^\dag$ I have to give what is its
action on $f$, i.e. $A^\dag f$. This is done assigning the scalar
product with any other $g$:

$$\intinf g^* (A^\dag f)\>dx\,\eqdf \intinf (A\,g)^* f\>dx.\tag1$$
By taking the complex conjugate of this equation you have
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g\,(A^\dag f)^*\,dx \eqdf 
  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (A\,g)\,f^*\,dx$$
or
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (A^\dag f)^* g\>dx \eqdf 
  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f^* (A\,g)\>dx$$
which shows, compared with (1), that $A^{\dag\dag} = A$.